# XPath for less than or equal to a percentage?

Tags: xml, xpath, wordpress

I'm using this code right now (XPath) with WP All Import for Wordpress to import large CSV files.

Here is the plugin doc:

http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/filtering-with-xpath/

```
/node[price[1] < old_price]
```

But I want that `price` is only 80% or less of `old_price`.
How can I code this? Is there a simple code, or I have to write a large new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath:

```
/node[price[1] &lt;= 0.8*old_price]
```